# Conversion of a general linear program into a standard linear program

Tags: inequality, optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to teach myself the basics of optimization of linear programmes, for example the following question:

[image]

How do I tackle such a question?

Comment: Do you know slack veriables ? Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable. If this is not clear, just post. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am aware of what slack variables are, but not how they relate to my question specifically. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality is $x_1-2x_2+x_3+x_4\leq 4$

To get an equality you have to add an slack variable. For this first inequality it is $y_1$.

All slack variable are $y_i \geq 0 \ \ \forall i$

$x_1-2x_2+x_3+x_4+y_1= 4$

In the second inequality you have to substract (another) slack variable:

$-x_1+3x_2-x_3+2x_4 -y_2=5$

Now all constraints are equalities. In the next step you have to make all variables greater or equal to zero.

---

$x_3 \leq 0$

Here you can say, that $x_3=-x_3'$. Thus the definiton set for $x_3'$ is $x_3'\geq 0$

And in the linear programm you just insert $-x_3'$ for $x_3$

For the objective function it is

$x_1+3x_2+2(-x_3')+x_4 \Rightarrow x_1+3x_2-2x_3'+x_4$

The same has to be done with the three constraints.

---

$x_2$ is a free variable. To get variables, which are greater or equal to zero, you define

$x_2=x_2^+-x_2^-$

$x_2^+,x_2^-\geq 0$

Thus the objective function is

$x_1+3(x_2^+-x_2^-)-2x_3'+x_4 \Rightarrow x_1+3x_2^+-3x_2^- -2x_3'+x_4$

The same has to be done with the three constraints.

After that, you repeat this step for $x_4$

---

After all, the definition set for all variables is $x_1,x_2^+,x_2^-,x_3',x_4^+,x_4^-,y_1,y_2 \geq 0$